# Unable to locate package after manual uninstall

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, uninstall

I installed waterfox from a third party repository using apt. I completely forgot that I installed it using apt and uninstalled it manually. When running apt remove waterfox, I receive a message "E: Unable to locate package waterfox".

I scanned through /var/lib/dpkg/status and uninstalled all waterfox related items. I've also searched the filenames of /etc, /opt, /usr, /var, /bin and /sbin for waterfox with no result.

I'm guessing waterfox is still mentioned somewhere in config files of apt or dpkg. However I'm not sure where they are located. I'd like to just remove the record of waterfox existing on the system so I'm not given an error when I try to run it. I'd like to know how I could go about doing that or any other alternative solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would try reinstalling, then removing the proper way (sudo apt remove).